# creating a copy of db using `mysqldump` command

Tags: mysql

Is there a way to create a copy of a database with sample rows using `mysqldump` command?

`myslqdump -u <username> -h <host> -p <database name> [<table name> ...]`

I have a fairly large DB and need to create a copy so that a developer can work with the App. Instead of dumping the entire DB, is there a way to randomly sample rows and create a copy of the `db`?

Comment: The problem with your approach is the natue of the relational databases: a random sample from all tables may lead to a dataset where parent rows do not have corresponding child rows and vica versa, child rows do not have parent rows. The former may lead to an unusable dataset, the latter would result in an error. You have to do the sampling programmatically as you are aware of the relationships, while mysqldump is not.

Answer (score 1):

Mysqldump does support row-level backup, as it has `--where` option which filters rows to be dumped.Here is what the reference manual says about it:
 ***--where='where_condition', -w 'where_condition'
Dump only rows selected by the given WHERE condition. Quotes around the condition are mandatory if it contains spaces or other characters that are special to your command interpreter.*** 
 But it might not be that user-friendly. Even if we put a subquery in a WHERE clause, we are still facing some restrictions which might not be possible to overcome. For instance, let's use actor table from DB sakila. It's legit to execute this in mysql cli:

```
select * from actor 
where actor_id in (select * 
                    from (select actor_id from actor order by rand() limit 5) t 
                    );

+----------+-------------+-----------+---------------------+
| actor_id | first_name  | last_name | last_update         |
+----------+-------------+-----------+---------------------+
|       19 | BOB         | FAWCETT   | 2006-02-15 04:34:33 |
|       91 | CHRISTOPHER | BERRY     | 2006-02-15 04:34:33 |
|       11 | ZERO        | CAGE      | 2006-02-15 04:34:33 |
|      120 | PENELOPE    | MONROE    | 2006-02-15 04:34:33 |
|      109 | SYLVESTER   | DERN      | 2006-02-15 04:34:33 |
+----------+-------------+-----------+---------------------+
```

However, it's erroneous to use the same WHERE clause when using mysqldump.

```
mysqldump -uroot -p  sakila actor --where="actor_id in (select * from (select actor_id from actor order by rand() limit 5) t )" > /tmp/acto
r_bck.sql

-- error message:
mysqldump: Couldn't execute 'SELECT /*!40001 SQL_NO_CACHE */ * FROM `actor` WHERE actor_id in (select * from (select actor_id from actor order by rand() limit 5) t )': Table 'actor' was not locked with LOCK TABLES (1100)
```

Besides, as Shadow stated, retaining referential integrity is an issue when using mysqldump. We don't want a broken relationship between tables and unusable dataset. With all regards, please do not use mysqldump for random row-level sampling.
Under the circumstances, the best I can come up with is to use a stored procedure to do the row-level backup to a new database,with contents like:

```
create database sakila_bck
create table sakila_bck.actor select * from sakila.actor order by rand() limit 10;
create table sakila_bck.actor_film select * from sakila.actor_film where actor_id in (select actor_id from sakila_bck.actor);
-- Note: The create table xx select * from yy does not create keys for backup table. By the way, if you want to retrieve a random number of rows, you can try the PREPARED statement to provide the `limit clause` with a randomly generated number beforehand.
```

The whole process is definitely not a pushover as we have to keep table relationship in mind. But once the job is done, we can safely use  mysqldump to dump  sakila_bck at DB-level.

Comment: Nice answer! I would also add that it is hard to imagine that a simple random sample rows will be sufficient for development purposes as the exported rows may not be a representative sample of the types of data within certain tables making the sample- again - unusable for testing purposes. Also, if the live data contains personally identifiable data, then these have to be obfuscated / masked in the development database.

Comment: I would also add that for the subquery solution to work for data integrity purposes, you need to pass a seed to mysql's rand() function, otherwise your random sample is not repeatable between the two tables.

Comment: Thank you for the elaboration. I was wondering if we should backup the whole DB first and do the DELETE JOB later, providing the DB size is not that huge. With ON DELETE CASCADE constraint it's easier to maintain data integrity , and the operation is simpler. Besides, in my opinion, having 30 people out of 100 people in the PK table and retain all those 30 people's related data in the FK table probably makes more sense than having 60 people out of 100 people in the PK table but only retain a minor part of those 60 people's  data in the FK table.

Comment: Yeah, there are lots of aspects that need to be considered. This is why I just provided a short comment and not an answer :)